# On click i need to change the UI with out push the new object for the same screen

Tags: blackberry

[image: First image]

[image: Second image]

The above images are of android app. The functionality is , If i click manage button, then cancel button will appear in place of manage button and sync button will be appeared at bottom of the screen. Can we implement this in BB OS 5.0 application without pushing the new screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, add [HorizontalFieldManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.1api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/HorizontalFieldManager.html) instance to the top of the screen and keep reference to it. Then add/remove fields to this manager according to your conditions.

Comment: @ Rafadel Osipov - I can use simple if condition and implement it. My question is on click of that button i need to change the manage button to cancel button.How can i do that? By pushing the new screen i can do it,but i want without  pushing a newScreen.

Comment: I did not mention you need to push a new screen. Keep references to both buttons and manager instance in your class. Let say they are `button1`, `button2` and `hfmanager`. Then implement a FieldChangeListener, add it to both buttons, and process click event. When button1 is clicked, `call hfmanager.delete(button1);` and `hfmanager.add(button2);`. And the same approach for the second button.

Comment: @Rafadel Osipov - In the above images,If you see On the First image the grey color image is overloaded,on Click of that image it should turn like the second image(i.e the green image should be overloaded) can u please tell the easiest way.(Now On Click of the image, i am adding that image to a list and pushing the new screen again, i am checking the image in selected List , if image is present i am overloading the green image).

Comment: Post another question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly manage button & Cancel button have same UI , so dont need to change the button just Simply change it label to manage to cancel. & on its navigation click , according to label perform task.

```
<Button Object>.setLabel("Cancel");
```

Add a horizontal manager in footer of your screen. Once you press for Manage add Snyc image to this HFM & once it completes , you can remove it.

I hope it may work for you , without replacing New screen.

Answer (score 1):

Using delete, add and insert methods of `Screen` / `Manager`, you can modify the UI anytime. Check following methods.

- [`public void deleteAll()`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html#deleteAll%28%29)
- [`public void delete(Field field)`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html#delete%28net.rim.device.api.ui.Field%29)
- [`public void insert(Field field, int index)`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html#insert%28net.rim.device.api.ui.Field,%20int%29)
- [`public void add(Field field)`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html#add%28net.rim.device.api.ui.Field%29)

To refresh / repaint any screen after modifying any `Screen` you can use any one of the following methods.

- [`public void invalidate()`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html#invalidate%28%29)
- [`protected void invalidate(int x, int y, int width, int height)`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html#invalidate%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)
- [`protected void invalidateFieldRange(int lower, int upper)`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html#invalidateFieldRange%28int,%20int%29)

And check the documentation of the [`Screen`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html) and [`Manager`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html) (`VerticalFieldManager`, `HorizontalFieldManager`) for more idea.